# Java extracting doubles out of a byte array

Tags: java, c, double, byte, arrays

I'm having trouble extracting a bunch of doubles from a byte array. Using c I was able to do this:

```
int16_t* data = (int16_t*)byte_array;
double st = data[0]; //first two bytes should be st or 29811
double et = data[9]; //last two bytes should be et or 29797
double accX = data[1];
double accY = data[2];
double accZ = data[3;
double gyroX = data[4];
...
>> st = 29811
>> et = 29797
```

But now I am trying to rewrite my code using java (android). The data I have coming is is correct because I can do:

```
double s = data[0];
Log.i(TAG, "s: "+s); //ascii value for s is 115
>> s: 115
```

But I need to be able to pull out the data in between the st and the et which are I think are all doubles. I have tried something like this:

```
double st = data[0]&0xff<<8|data[1];
>> st: 115
```

Which didn't work. I don't have many other ideas, and don't know my low level byte manipulation very well.

Comment: I recommend at least using parentheses... `((data[0] & 0xff) << 8) | (data[1] & 0xff)`

Comment: Is there any reason to `& 0xff`? I didn't think there was, but I saw a ton of other answers where people did it.

Comment: `byte`s are signed in Java. So 255 becomes -1, 254 becomes -2, ..., 128 becomes -128. `& 0xff` is a quick way to undo that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) might help, as it lets you read the IEEE 754 representation of `double`s.  That said, your C code looks like it's getting 16 bits at a time, for which you might call `ByteBuffer.getShort()`?

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
double st = buf.getShort();
double accX = buf.getShort();
double accY = buf.getShort();
...
double et = buf.getShort();
```

Comment: How do I account for the offset though?

Comment: Call `getShort(offset)`?

Comment: Perfect. After looking into the ByteBuffer some more, (this is a 'duh' moment) I found that it works like a buffer, so everytime you call getShort() it moves through the array to the next values.

Comment: That works too.  You can either specify absolute offsets yourself or just call `get` methods to walk through the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two problems with your code:

```
double st = data[0]&0xff<<8|data[1];
```

is parsed as:

```
double st = ((data[0] & (0xff << 8)) | data[1];
```

You should use parentheses and spaces to make your code both more readable and consistent with your ideas.

Second problem: you assume big endian byte ordering, which is rather rare these days.

Incidentally, what is the type of `data` in java?

Comment: data is a byte array.